# Use aws-cdk props to import security groups created on another stack

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-cdk-typescript

I would like to use props.security group but i can't reference the stack that created the security group

```
const vpc_stack = new VpcStack(
    app, 
    'vpc-stack',
    {...}
    });

const sg_stack = new SecurityGroupStack(
    app, 
    'sg-stack', 
    {
        vpc: vpc_stack.vpc,    
...
    });


const asg_stack = new AsgStack(
    
    app,
    'asg-stack'
    {
        vpc: vpc_stack.vpc,    **<===========this works**
        SecurityGroup: sg_stack. , **<====== It doesn't let add SuperGroup or SuperGroupId**
        prefixName: 'InfrastructureCdk',
        env: env,
        depl: `${process.env.AWS_ENV}`,
        description: "Infrastructure SG Stack",
        
    }
)
```

Can't find an answer on documentation

I'm expecting to import the SG using Props **not** import/export

Comment: Your stack has to have a class field that exposes this variable.